# Cannot deploy MDB with durable subscription(topic) in EJB2.1 for Glassfish 4

Tags: glassfish, jms, message-driven-bean, ejb-2.x

I am in the process of migrate from OC4J to glassfish and struggles to deploy MDBs with durable subscriptions on Glassfish4

The class MyObserver implements MessageDrivenBean and MessageListener and is registered with a topic 
Created topic:

```
asadmin create-jms-resource --restype=javax.jms.Topic --description="Topic for EventObjectMessage(s)" --property Name=PhysicalTopic jms/EventObjectMessageTopic
```

created topic factory:

```
asadmin create-jms-resource --restype=javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory --description="Topic factory" --property ClientId=EventObjectMessageTopicConnectionFactoryID EventObjectMessageTopicConnectionFactory
```

created physical destination:

```
asadmin create-jmsdest --desttype topic EventObjectMessageTopic
```

in ejb-jar.xml:

```
<message-driven>
            <ejb-name>MyObserver </ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.firm.MyObserver </ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-selector>qualifiedName = 'com.firm.EventObjectMessage' AND objectsClassName = 'com.firm.SomeObject'</message-selector>
            <acknowledge-mode>Auto-acknowledge</acknowledge-mode>
            <message-driven-destination>
                <destination-type>javax.jms.Topic</destination-type>
                <subscription-durability>Durable</subscription-durability>
            </message-driven-destination>
... a lot of refs
</message-driven>
```

and glassfish-ejb-jar.xml

```
<ejb>
            <ejb-name>MyObserver </ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>jms/EventObjectMessageTopic</jndi-name>
            <mdb-resource-adapter>
                <activation-config>
                    <activation-config-property>
                        <activation-config-property-name>clientId</activation-config-property-name>
                        <activation-config-property-value>EventObjectMessageTopicConnectionFactoryID</activation-config-property-value>
                    </activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property>
                        <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionName</activation-config-property-name>
                        <activation-config-property-value>ASubscriptionName</activation-config-property-value>
                    </activation-config-property>                   
                </activation-config>
            </mdb-resource-adapter>
        </ejb>
```

This is part of the stacktrace:

```
[2014-01-07T08:44:44.308+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1389080684308] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.resource.NotSupportedException: MQRA:EC:Error creating Direct Message Consumer:
createConsumer on JMSService:jmsdirect failed for connectionId:8664718337762585088 and sessionId:8664718337762587904 due to [B4135]: Cannot add durable consumer MyObserver. No ClientID was set on connection.
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.createDirectMessageConsumer(EndpointConsumer.java:890)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer._init(EndpointConsumer.java:345)
```

I am not sure if clientId should only be set on the connectionfactory and as a mdb-resource-adapter as I did.
Does anyone have a tip or could point out what i miss.

Best regards Geir